# HowTo select an Element by its ID (d3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some Problems with d3-selection.
I did it hundrets of times in my Project but now I have a hole in my head.

```
var draggedLine = d3.select('line');
```

works as expected (Returns the first line)

```
var draggedLine = d3.select('#76');
```

throws a Syntax Error in d3.v4.js.

d3.v4.min.js:2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#76' is not a valid selector.

What is wrong here? 
(of Course the Element with id="76" exists. It's a Group Element)

Comment: `76` is not a valid ID. Since SVG is an XML document IDs must adhere to the [Name production](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name) rule, which disallows digits as the starting character. Instead of bending your code to work with malformed IDs you will probably be better of renaming your IDs. Otherwise, your code might suddenly break in the future because you relied on some non-standard behavior.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will give my IDs a letter in front of the number. 
The Number, I Need for "Connection" to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution** 
Try this

```
var draggedLine = d3.select('[id="76"]');
```

Note: id should not start with number for better approach